Gapping in Dynamically Created User Controls
I am trying to programically/dynamically create some user control, since there will be a variable number of display elements.
The following code makes something that looks like this:

This looks exactly how I want! The user control Station has the border, which I use just as a guideline.
I then try to make 4 of these in a square, but there's weird spacing between them that doesn't change even with the Margin and Padding properties set to 0. I generated this with the following code:

How can I get rid of the gaps between Stations?
I tried different things, like making all elements have 0 padding and margin, I tried using Left/Right/Top/Bottom properties instead of location, but I can't find anything to get rid of this gap.
Station Code:
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace NewOPCMotion.CustomComponents
{
    public partial class Station : UserControl
    {
        private int _StationNumber;
        private int _StationPosition;

        public Station()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Base all dimensions off of lb_Station
            lb_StnNo.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            lb_StnNo.Size = new Size(Constants.STATION_LB_WIDTH, Constants.STATION_LB_HEIGHT);

            // Center DPS in lb_Station
            DPS.Location = new Point((lb_StnNo.Size.Width - DPS.Size.Width) / 2, (lb_StnNo.Size.Height - DPS.Height) / 2);
            Motor.Location = new Point((lb_StnNo.Size.Width - Motor.Size.Width) / 2, lb_StnNo.Size.Height);

            // SV immediately right to lb_Station
            SV.Location = new Point(lb_StnNo.Width + 1, 1);

            // S1/S2 location
            S1.Location = new Point(lb_StnNo.Left + Constants.SENSOR_OFFSET, lb_StnNo.Size.Height - (S2.Height + 1));
            S2.Location = new Point(lb_StnNo.Right - S2.Width - Constants.SENSOR_OFFSET, lb_StnNo.Size.Height - (S2.Height + 1));

            // Panel size
            pnl_Station.Size = new Size(SV.Right, Motor.Bottom);

            //// Control size
            Size = new Size(pnl_Station.Size.Width, pnl_Station.Size.Height);
            //Padding = new Padding(0);
            //Margin = new Padding(0);

        }

        public void SetLocation(int X, int Y)
        {
            pnl_Station.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        }

        // Properties
        public int StationNumber
        {
            get { return _StationNumber; } 
            set
            {
                _StationNumber = value;
                lb_StnNo.Text = "Stn " + StationNumber.ToString();
            } 
        }
        public int StationPosition
        {
            get { return _StationPosition; }   // get method
            set { _StationPosition = value; }  // set method
        }
    }
}

Module Code:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NewOPCMotion.CustomComponents
{
    public partial class ProcessModule : UserControl
    {
        private Station[] Stations;
        private Panel ModulePanel;

        public ProcessModule()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Stations = new Station[4];
            ModulePanel = pnl_Module;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Stations[i] = new Station();
                Stations[i].StationPosition = i;
                Stations[i].Margin = new Padding(0);
                Stations[i].Padding = new Padding(0);
                ModulePanel.Controls.Add(Stations[i]);
            }

            // Place W, X, Y, Z Stations
            ModulePanel.Controls[0].Location = new Point(0, 0);
            ModulePanel.Controls[1].Location = new Point(ModulePanel.Controls[0].Right, 0);
            ModulePanel.Controls[2].Location = new Point(ModulePanel.Controls[0].Right, ModulePanel.Controls[0].Bottom);
            ModulePanel.Controls[3].Location = new Point(0, ModulePanel.Controls[0].Bottom);
            // Size = new Size(Constants.STATION_WIDTH * 2, Constants.STATION_HEIGHT * 2);

        }
        public void SetStationNumbers(int ModuleNumber)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                // TODO: Set station numbers
                Stations[i].StationNumber = i;
            }
            
        }

        public void SetLocation(int X, int Y)
        {
            ModulePanel.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        }
    }
}


The issue is with the width.  Why are you adding one?

@jdweng do you mean in "SV.Location = new Point(lb_StnNo.Width + 1, 1);"? That's there so there's a small space between that and lb_Station. It overlaps without it. Even if i remove that tiny offset there is still a huge gap between Stations.

The station image may have a large white space that can't be changed.  Then you would have to overlap to get rid of the white space.

@jdweng there clearly is not a white space for the Station image as you can see the outline of the border of the Station user control. There is a white space between each station component, which you can see by looking between the outlines.

There are specialized layout controls that have engines to position and/or size the hosted controls based on the current display settings. The FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel in particular. Try the former for your problem. Don't forget to make your app Dpi-aware.
